# Order by causing slower select in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, database-performance

I have a table that will have transaction records inserted by various program, and i shall process them one by one. The records are selected one by one, and there is a priority field where the lowest number shall be processed first.

My current query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CODE,NAME,TYPE,START_DATE, LANGUAGE, PRIORITY, SOURCE 
FROM TBL_INQUEUE ORDER BY PRIORITY) q WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

When the data set becomes large, the query will become slower to run. We had added index on the `PRIORITY` column but it doesn't help. We tried removing the `ORDER BY` clause and the performance has almost double, but we need the clause to make sure the prioritized records get to be processed first.

Is there a way to optimize this?

**UPDATE**

With the answers provided, here are the two explain plans:

*With Order By using Index*

[image]

*With MAX(PRIORITY)*

[image]

Comment: Show the explain plans, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PRIORITY is set to NOT NULL, is it? The index will not be used otherwise.

You can workaround that issue by creating a composite function-based index on (PRIORITY, 0), though, or by including "where priority is not null" in the query.

Comment: Ah thanks, it seems that NOT having NOT NULL on the PRIORITY column is the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would help?

```
SELECT CODE,NAME,TYPE,START_DATE, LANGUAGE, PRIORITY, SOURCE 
FROM TBL_INQUEUE 
WHERE PRIORITY = (SELECT MAX(PRIORITY) FROM TBL_INQUEUE)
AND ROWNUM = 1
```

NB: Using "and rownum=1" is arbitrary; that is, if there are multiple rows that share the MAX(PRIORITY) value any of those rows could be chosen.

Comment: Sorry just got to try this. This works too and from the explain plan seems to be faster (with the index support).

Comment: great, I thought it would be useful at least. thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Can you post the two explain plans?

Comment: Sure. It's holiday here today. Will post tomorrow when i'm back at work.

Comment: Had uploaded the two explain plans as promised.